# How can I display a selected value of a multivalue entity reference field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have two content types `A` and `B`.

There is a multi valued field `Persons` in content type `B`. I have created a node of type `B` and enter two values in `Persons` field, `X` and `Y`.

Content type `A` has an entity reference field to Content type `B` which displays the values of the `Persons` field.

I created a node of type `A` and selected `X` in that entity reference field.

Now I have a view which is displaying the content of `A`. But I am unable to display the selected value of that entity reference field.

It displays the node id or the node title or all the values of the `Persons` field.

Is there any way to display the selected value of the `Persons` field in the view of listing the content of `A`?

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense, you can't be selecting from Person options in A nodes if the entityreference is referencing content B. The entityrefence fields aren't referencing field values. Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish without making assumptions about technology? You can't easily get the values of B nodes when creating A node, because the form hasn't yet been saved. Maybe investigate this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263074/entity-reference-widget-selctor-in-view-referring-same-reference/263335#263335

Comment: The way i read the question, makes me believe that the 1st x is not the same as the 2nd x.

Comment: I want a field in A which can save a value of a multi valued field of B. Is it clear now?