# Help with Views Relationships and Entity References

Tags: 7, views

This is my scenario:
I have three content types,
Content type A is linked to Content type B with an Entity reference field .
Content type C is linked to Content type B with an Entity reference field

What I would like to achieve is a view, to be shown on type A nodes, showing all type C nodes that have the same relation to type B.

Any hint?

Comment: Found this solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/1664526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called "sibling" nodes, and you can do it with the help of two Relationships and one Contextual filter.

List Content C in a View, then add the first Relationship for the Entity reference field on that type.

Add the second Relationship that goes in reverse from the field to the content (Content using field_[referencename]). The second Relationship must use the first Relationship.

Then add the Contextual filter for node ID that uses the second Relationship. That will recognize which node A you're on and also filter out only content C that have in common through content B reference.

For more details see in this answer (look at Relationship and Contextual configuration steps): [Entity Reference widget selctor in view referring same reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263074/entity-reference-widget-selctor-in-view-referring-same-reference/263335#263335)