# View to get information for the user entity reference using contextual filters

Tags: views, 9

I have two content types and each one has a user entity reference field.   I want a view using contextual filter that shows the information of the content types when I pass the user ID referenced for the user entity reference field.

content-type 1:  field -> studies, field -> id-user-entity-reference
content-type 2:  field -> experience, field -> id-user-entity-reference

I want to get for example studies and experience in a view when I have a path similar like that:

/content/id-user-entity-reference (not the logged user, not the author id of the content type)

I need these results can be exposed via rest.

How can I configure my view to achieve that?

Comment: Try searching for sibling entity reference views, there are many answers with examples on how to achieve something like that. Here's one you can study: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263074/entity-reference-widget-selctor-in-view-referring-same-reference/263335#263335

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it.